# Notifications when Bluetooth device is found

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to set up a notification to flash from my app when a certain bluetooth device is found, I have tried googling how to do this but can only find notifications triggered by timers or dates. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Which kind of bluetooth device you want to connect? You cannot do for normal bluetooth device.

Comment: Im using a BLE beacon, i want the app to recognise the correct beacon then display a notification if it is in the background

Comment: Is it Estimote?

Comment: Im not sure, I don't think so